# How can I find the "missing" time in this kCacheGrind output?

Tags: kcachegrind, callgrind

I'm analyzing kCacheGrind (really WinCacheGrind) to analyze cachegrind files and when the "self" times of each process are added up, the total comes nowhere near the cumulative time of the entire page.  More specifically, the self time of the entire page is 6,561ms, but the cumulative time of the children within {main} only add up to 96ms.

Any ideas how to best go about identifying the "missing" time?

Unfortunately, I'm new and so can't include an image but hopefully I've given enough to start.  If not, let me know what I can provide.

Thanks.

Edit: here's what I'm seeing http://www.flickr.com/photos/76072991@N02/6832545235/

Comment: Feel free to include URLs in comments; almost always some kind higher-rep user will include the image for you.